# polyline can not be remove from google map

Tags: android, polyline

I try remove polyline from google map but can not be remove marked point, how to remove polyline?

```
  mFabClearAllPins = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_all_clear);

    mFabClearAllPins.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mPolyLine!=null)
            mPolyLine.remove();
            googleMap.clear();

        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting some runtime error or something and if yes, what error are you running into?
Show some **code** how you are adding the polylines. Also, try putting a breakpoint inside the click listener and see what is going on?

Comment: Am calculating the area, once click the clear all button map and polyline only removed then after calculate button pressed yellow color marked polyline showing the map.how to completely clear.

Comment: `googleMap.clear();` should have removed all overlays including polylines. Did you some how draw it again?